# Multiple Language Support in WP8 app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

For my WP8 app i want to provide support for several languages. For this I'm currently using *.resw files in order to store language specific text for needed xaml elements. I also defined the default language (en-US) within the *.appxmanifest.

Regarding my project's file organization, I created several language files used for different groups of information, e.g. button context ("AppBarButtons.resw") or pivot header ("PivotHeader.resw").

But now I'm not quite sure if this is the best solution. What would be if there are elements on different pages, all with the same `x:Uid` property?

So my question is, should i stick to this solution or shall I create a language file for each page individually, and how can I let the user choose a specific language (only if available for this app of course) programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create only one .resw file per language. Creating one per form is going to become a very difficult solution to maintain over time, especially if you share terms between forms. Also use the  x:Uid notation in the xaml when possible this makes life so much easier. I found the following video from Microsoft on languages in windows phone to be quite helpful ...

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/08

If wanting to use the same translations such as in the app bar  save button for example: the XAML would look like as follows...

```
<AppBarButton x:Uid="AppBarSave" Label=""  Icon="Save" Click="AppBarButtonSave_Click"/>
```

The resource file would like like the following:

[image]

Comment: Great tip, I'm using the Multilingual Tool from now on, it handles things pretty good.

Comment: But I still need to know how I can handle single elements (on different pages), all with the same `x:Uid`. This is because I have multiple `AppBarButton`'s on a `BottomAppBar` with the same functionality, like "Add", but it's specific to the page's context, and I don't want to name the button elements its `x:Uid` individually for each page!

Comment: Alright, that's kind of nice to use several elements (of the same type) with equal `x:Uid`'s, thx